# How to generate the table schema from INFORMATION_SCHEMA in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I trying to generate table structure using INFORMATION_SCHEMA in MySQL. 
I need the same output as

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE Mytablename;
```

My intention is to generation create table script for list of tables in mysql. 
please help. I need to take table scripts for 100 tables. like below

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_list` (
`ID` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`name` varchar(91) DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`zip_code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`notes` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`SID` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: If you are using MySQL Workbench on **Data Export** select your tables and click  `Dump Structure Only`

Answer (score 2):

SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query to get the table structure from the INFORMATION SCHEMA is as follows, where the database name is "dbname" and the table name is "Mytablename":

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'Mytablename';
```

Comment: But I need the output like, "Create table MyTableName ( Id int,Name varchar(10));". I mean exactly what we get from SHOW CREATE TABLE TableName

Comment: Why don`t you run this query SHOW CREATE TABLE Mytablename; directly?

Comment: I need to take scripts for 100 tables.

Comment: Kindly explain your question a bit more and make an edit to the question.